# Java client consume ASP.Net Webservice

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services, client

We are porting a C# module to Java. This module consume ASP.Net Webservice. C# Module use CookieContainer to help ASP.Net Webservice distinguish between sessions. What is equivalent in Java?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `getSession()` method on the [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) interface.

You might want to reference this primer on [Java servlets](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-First-Servlets.html) as well.

Comment: Is it ok if our app client is in android?

Comment: Does it matter what your client platform is? The server should be the piece concerned with sessions.